# Apache Kafka issue when zookeeper is down and came up after 5 min

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose the zookeeper is down somehow for 5 min and we have kafka up and running.And after 5 min when the zookeeper is up we see duplicate record getting send to consumer. Any solution for it?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using the old consumer. You shouldn't see this with the new consumer API (available post 0.9). However, it's generally not a good thing if zookeeper goes down so you should work on making sure that doesn't happen as much as possible.

Comment: will check and update you